# How to add subtitle to your app in playstore?

Tags: android, ios, optimization

[image: A screenshot of Google Play shows three cryptocurrency-related apps. Each of them is marked as an "Ad", and contains a subtitle with a brief description of the app in italics.]

As shown in the image, you can see the subtitles under the app name. How can we add this subtitle to our app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did short desc works for you? as pic blow

[image]

Comment: No, short description appears when we open the app detail and see in "About this App", for example BitKeep app, as you can see it is written under it "Real time price and Charts", so when i open the detail of this app and i read full description but this text "Real time price and Charts" not found anywhere.

Comment: I noticed that such text is appearing only under the promoted apps.

Comment: @partyush, I guess so